# VBA excel importing data from notepad on matching a condition in notepad into excel

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Read_text_file()

    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim myLine As String
    Dim FileNum As Long

    myFileName = "D:\Users\sok\Desktop\output.file.txt"    '  change the text file Location
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Close FileNum
    Open myFileName For Input As FileNum
    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, myLine
       MsgBox myLine, OK
    Loop

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me to insert a specific line of Notepad into Excel sheet on matching a condition? We need to add new logic to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking to add condition check in your code. If it is so do the following:

```
Sub Read_text_file()

    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim myLine As String
    Dim FileNum As Long

    myFileName = "D:\Users\sok\Desktop\output.file.txt"    '  change the text file Location
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Close FileNum
    Open myFileName For Input As FileNum
    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, myLine

        If myLine = "abc" Then    '---> put your condition here
            MsgBox myLine, OK     '---> do your stuff if condition is true
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

If your requirement is something else let me know.

**EDIT #1**: 
**______________________________________________________________________________**

```
Sub Read_text_file()

    Dim FileNum As Long: FileNum = FreeFile
    Dim myLine() As String, i As Long
    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim lineToCheck As Long

    myFileName = "D:\Users\sok\Desktop\output.file.txt"    '  change the text file Location

    Open myFileName For Input As #FileNum
        myLine = Split(Input$(LOF(FileNum), #FileNum), vbNewLine)
    Close #FileNum

    lineToCheck = 10    '---> enter line number of notepad file that you want to check

    For i = 0 To UBound(myLine)
        If myLine(i) = myLine(lineToCheck - 1) Then '---> this is your condition
            MsgBox myLine(i), OK                    '---> do your stuff if condition is true
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that.Can we add a specific line of notepad as a condition rather than a string and do operations on next line?

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help. Can you just help me to replace the notepad value on the line to check and add it in a cell. You can take any cell  for example. As I am not a VB guy it is very difficult for me to create the code.Please just help me one last time in this?

Comment: @Abhinav - Sorry, not able understand what exactly you are asking for.

Comment: @Abhinav - Which line do you want to add from notepad to excel cell?

Comment: You can add line no 6

Comment: Add this line to any excel cell. I just need an example. Thanks

Comment: @Abhinav - To add line from notepad to excel cell write `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = myLine(i)`

Comment: @Abhinav - This will add the line to cell `A1` of `Sheet1` in the `Acitive Workbook`.

Comment: I have tried this but it is throwing an error subscript out of range.

Comment: @Abhinav - That error is thrown probably because you are not assigning `i` value properly. May be value assigned to `i` is greater the number of lines in the notepad file. Check your notepad file.

Comment: Thanx  for your continued support. I will try but it is not working!! is it because of the Activeworkbook error??

Comment: @Abhinav - Don't think so. Can you share your file online so that I can look into it.

Comment: Thanx a lot.it is working fine now.Huge relief!! Will contact you in case of any further support.

Comment: @Abhinav - Oh Great! If my answer solved your question kindly mark it as an answer.

Comment: How can I add a for loop with a condition cell no say 9 to until I find an empty cell?

Comment: Or can I add a for loop from a specifc number to a certain cell value by matching a condition in the cell value for loop?

Comment: @Abhinav - If you can provide sample image, it will be easier for me to understand what actually you want.